# Compare two dataframes and print out updated rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I'm quite new to R, and I'm trying to solve this problem that seems quite simple, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm trying to compare two dataframes, and print out the rows that are in one but not the other, and also print another list/dataframe with the rows where only one cell has been updated.

```
df1
firstname  lastname email
Grace       Holly   hollyoaks@yahoo.com
Trish       Edison  edisontrish@gmail.com

df2
firstname lastname  email
Grace     Holly     rickyoaks@yahoo.com
Frederick Sam       sammic@gmail.com
```

The first thing I wanted to do was get the rows that were in df2 and not in df1, and this is how I did it:

```
require(sqldf)

df2NotIndf1 <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM df2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM df1')
```

This gave me the output:

```
`firstname lastname  email`
`Frederick Sam       sammic@gmail.com`
```

Now, what I want is a way to get the first row as an output of it's own, by noting that the first and last name are the same, but the email is different.

So, I want a way to print out:

```
firstname  lastname  email

Grace     Holly     rickyoaks@yahoo.com
```

I've looked at the compare () function, and the merge and other functions, but they seem to be comparing to spot different rows, instead of different cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If you are looking for a way to list those people whose firstname and lastname are in both df1 and df2 but whose email is different then:

```
sqldf("select df1.*, df2.email email2 
  from df1 
  join df2 on df1.firstname = df2.firstname and 
              df1.lastname = df2.lastname and 
              df1.email <> df2.email")
```

giving the following which shows the df1 record and the differing email from df2.

```
  firstname lastname               email              email2
1     Grace    Holly hollyoaks@yahoo.com rickyoaks@yahoo.com
```

**2)** or a base solution would be:

```
subset(merge(df1, df2, by = 1:2), email.x != email.y)
```

### Note

The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines1 <- "firstname  lastname email
Grace       Holly   hollyoaks@yahoo.com
Trish       Edison  edisontrish@gmail.com"

Lines2 <- "firstname lastname  email
Grace     Holly     rickyoaks@yahoo.com
Frederick Sam       sammic@gmail.com"

df1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I create the data frames.

```
# Create data frames
df1 <- read.table(text = "firstname  lastname email
                  Grace       Holly   hollyoaks@yahoo.com
                  Trish       Edison  edisontrish@gmail.com", ,
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "firstname lastname  email
Grace     Holly     rickyoaks@yahoo.com
Frederick Sam       sammic@gmail.com", 
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Next, I load `dplyr`.

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
```

Here, I perform an antijoin to find the rows in `df2` that are not in `df1`.

```
# Perform antijoin
df3 <- df2 %>% anti_join(df1, by = c("firstname", "lastname"))

#   firstname lastname            email
# 1 Frederick      Sam sammic@gmail.com
```

Then, I bind together the original two data frames, remove the row identified earlier as only appearing in `df2`, then I check for duplicates using all columns except one. If there are duplicates in all column except for one, I keep those rows.

```
# Bind two data frames together
# Remove those only appearing in df2
# Filter to those with duplicates in all but one column
df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df2) %>% 
  anti_join(df3) %>% 
  filter((duplicated(firstname, lastname) + duplicated(email, lastname) + duplicated(firstname, email)) == ncol(df1) - 1)

#   firstname lastname               email
# 1     Grace    Holly rickyoaks@yahoo.com
```

I'm currently thinking about a more succinct way of writing the `filter` line that generalises to an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I have also tried another solution, based on a similar question I spotted:

Comment: I have also tried another solution, based on a similar question I spotted:   


`email_change <- anti_join(df2, df1)
email_update_only <- inner_join(email_change, df2, by = c("firstname", "lastname"), suffix = c(".df1", ".df2")) %>% 
 filter(email.df2 != email.df1)`

It solved the two questions, about finding the rows not in the other dataframe, as well as picking the row with only the email as as the difference.  Your solution is neater though :)